# What is the SQL Query for inserting new Order in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I was using WooCommerce APIs to creating a new order in Woocommerce but that is slowing down the application too much.

I am planning to perform the new order operation directly by running a SQL query. Can anyone define the SQL query for Inserting a new order into the database?

I tried logging the SQL code that runs while the API is running but it is giving me more than 200 lines of output which are irrelevant.

Comment: How do You expect to speed up creating orders by doing new SQL query ? For me(in my opinion) in doesn't  help. Better to try using object caching and improve server side performance.

Comment: Object caching will solve my purpose only to fetch new objects but it won't help in inserting new order.

WooCommerce performs lots of complex operations via PHP to insert the order and inserts several rows for a single order. For example, it will extract user_id from the session and then process the things ahead. 

In my case, I have the user_id and other essential things which I need to create an order. I just need a SQL query which I will use to create a new order which will not use PHP.

Answer (score 0):

While using WooCommerce APIs is generally recommended for creating orders, below are SQL queries for users who prefer to create orders directly in the database.
These queries will affect 9 tables in the WordPress database, each serving a specific purpose in the WooCommerce order process.

Affected tables:
**wp_wc_orders**: Stores information about orders.
**wp_wc_orders_meta**: Contains metadata associated with orders.
**wp_wc_order_addresses**: Stores billing and shipping addresses for orders.
**wp_wc_order_operational_data**: Contains operational data related to orders.
**wp_woocommerce_order_items**: Stores information about items in orders.
**wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta**: Contains metadata associated with order items.
**wp_posts**: General purpose WordPress table where orders are stored.
**wp_wc_order_stats**: Stores statistical data related to orders.
**wp_wc_order_product_lookup**: Provides a lookup table for orders and products.

```
SET @user_id = 1;
SET @user_email = "test@gmail.com";
SET @order_status = 'wc-completed';
SET @amount = 1000;
SET @product_id = 14;
SET @product_qty = 1;
SET @order_id = 3;


INSERT INTO wp_wc_orders (id, status, currency, type, tax_amount, total_amount, customer_id, billing_email, date_created_gmt, date_updated_gmt, parent_order_id) 
VALUES (@order_id, @order_status, 'USD', 'shop_order', 0, @amount, @user_id, @user_email, UTC_TIMESTAMP(), UTC_TIMESTAMP(), 0);

INSERT INTO wp_wc_orders_meta (order_id, meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES 
(@order_id, '_billing_address_index', @user_email),
(@order_id, '_shipping_address_index', '');

INSERT INTO wp_wc_order_addresses (order_id, address_type, email)
VALUES (@order_id, 'billing', @user_email);


INSERT INTO wp_wc_order_operational_data (order_id, created_via, date_paid_gmt, date_completed_gmt) 
VALUES (@order_id, 'admin', UTC_TIMESTAMP(), UTC_TIMESTAMP());

INSERT INTO wp_woocommerce_order_items (order_item_name, order_item_type, order_id) 
VALUES ('test', 'line_item', @order_id);

SET @order_item_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta (order_item_id, meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES 
(@order_item_id, '_product_id', @product_id),
(@order_item_id, '_variation_id', 0),
(@order_item_id, '_line_total', @amount),
(@order_item_id, '_qty', @product_qty);



INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_author, post_date, post_date_gmt, post_content, post_title, post_status, comment_status, ping_status, post_name, post_modified, post_modified_gmt, post_parent, guid, post_type)
VALUES (@user_id, NOW(), NOW(), '', '', 'draft', 'closed', 'closed', '', NOW(), NOW(), 0, CONCAT('https://smhlotfizadeh.ir/?post_type=shop_order_placehold&p=', @order_id), 'shop_order_placehold');



INSERT INTO wp_wc_order_stats (order_id, parent_id, date_created, date_created_gmt, date_paid, date_completed, num_items_sold, total_sales, tax_total, shipping_total, net_total, returning_customer, status, customer_id)
VALUES (@order_id, 0, NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP(), NOW(), NOW(), @product_qty, @amount, 0, 0, @amount, 0, @order_status, @user_id);



INSERT INTO wp_wc_order_product_lookup (order_item_id, order_id, product_id, variation_id, customer_id, date_created, product_qty, product_net_revenue, product_gross_revenue, coupon_amount, tax_amount, shipping_amount, shipping_tax_amount) 
VALUES (@order_item_id, @order_id, @product_id, 0, @customer_id, UTC_TIMESTAMP(), @product_qty, @amount, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

**Note:** Customize the first one's variables according to your order:
@user_id: the id of the user that the order was created for.
@user_email: The email of the user that the order was created for.
@order_status: the status of the order.
@amount: the payment amount.
@product_id: The id of the product this order is related to.
@product_qty: the quantity of the product purchase (How many products the user purchased?)
@order_id: Find an ‘id’ in the wp_wc_orders table that is not exists.

**Note:** Please don’t run the queries separately, because some of them are using the previous query's primary key as the foreign key. Only run queries in this order.